# jQuery Masonry mobile 2 column layout fix

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to get the "mobile" layout of this page to display a 2-column layout, but either Masonry, or the CSS is forcing it down to 1-column.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EcuU7/

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

html
`

```
            <li class="item w3 stamp stamp-here">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/746/428" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/300" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/150" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/400" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item w2">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/495/400" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/320" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item w2">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/495/495" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/234" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/300" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/234" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/300" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/150" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/400" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item w2">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/495/400" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/320" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item w2">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/495/495" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/234" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/300" alt="">
            </li>

            <li class="item">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/245/234" alt="">
            </li>


        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

bro, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/EcuU7/1/

I added

`img{
    max-width:90%;
}` and
`max-width:250px;` for grid li

Comment: Hey man, I have the same problem. I was wondering if you would be so kind to take a look at [my site](https://keebs.com) and let me know how I can make it two columns for mobile.